Why do not some code change the dtype of the pandas column?
I tried to change the dtype of the string type column(with date) to datetime.
So, initially the column type was 'object', and expected final dtype was datetime64.
I tried this code for changing.
my_df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'])

But the dtype of my_df['date'] is still 'object'.
After checking that, I tried other code.
my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'])

In this time, the dtype was changed!
Why is this happened?

I guess that this was a design decision to have a consistent behavior because if you write something like my_df.loc[5:50, 'date'] =..., the dtype can't be changed.

As per the suggested duplicate: since pd 2.0.x df.loc[:, foo] = bar will attempt to set values inplace before falling back to casting. In your example, it is possible to set the values inplace, so there is no need for casting: the dtype doesn't change.

Compare the following: if you change the type to 'string' first (my_df['date'] = my_df['date'].astype('string')), you'll find that my_df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date']) does change the dtype, since in this case only setting in place will not work.
